# Need help downloading JDK

Tags: java, download

I have already gotten The Jcreator program installed, now i just need help with downloading JDK, whenever I run Jcreator I get this error :

```
 Failed to start the following executable, \bin\javac.exe -g -classpath "C:\Users\IDOTASDAS\Documents\JCreator LE\MyProjects\Stupid\classes" -d C:\Users\IDOTASDAS\Documents\JCreator" "LE\MyProjects\Stupid\classes C:\Users\IDOTASDAS\Documents\JCreator" LE\MyProjects\Stupid\src\Stupid.java 
 For help, please refer to http://www.jcreator.com/installation.htm

Process completed.
```

so I go to the site, download the software, and this error continues to pop up. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just download the JDK from [the official site.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Comment: Thats the same site I went to, and I downloaded I. Then, i compiled my javascript program, and then it told me to go to the same site your mentioning.

Comment: You mean java, not javascript, right? Also, make sure that JCreator knows where the java file is(PATH variable) and make sure JCreator is compiling it in the same version as the JDK you downloaded.